# Find Columns whose values are distinct in two tables without union

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables having same columns.I want to get those columns whose values are distinct in both tables.How Can I achieve this?please help.Iam stuck.

imageid is primary key in both tables.Its not necessary that imageids present in first table should be present on second table.

```
first table

imageid  name         id
1        priya        001
2        neha         002
3        divya        003
4        santo        004

second table

imageid  name         id
1        priy         001
2        neha         003
4        santo        004

Result

imageid firstdata  seconddata  columnname
1        priy         priya     name
2        002          003        id
```

I have tried this-

```
select t1.imageid, t1.name as firstdata, t2.name as seconddata, 'name' as colname
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.imageid = t2.imageid
where t1.name <> t2.name
union all
select t1.imageid, t1.id as firstdata, t2.id as seconddata, 'id'
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.imageid = t2.imageid
where t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Actually I Have 136 columns and I want query to be optimized.

Comment: I think you'll need dynamic SQL if you have too many columns.

Comment: Could you give some example please

Comment: Start by simply identifying the rows that have differences. Since missing imageID values are not an error, start with a query like this:  `SELECT t1.Id INTO #tmpIDs FROM FirstTable t1 INNER JOIN SecondTable t2 ON t1.ImageID = t2.ImageId WHERE t1.name != t2.name OR t1.id != t2.id OR ...` through all of the fields. This leaves you with a limited number of rows to process (hopefully).

Comment: You could use CHECKSUM(*) to find the rows that are different between the two tables.

Comment: Checksum() and Binary_Checksum() are a good idea for finding rows with differences. Do remember, however, that the *text, ntext, image, xml, and cursor* data types do not participate in a checksum. If these types of fields must be compared, then more code will be needed.

Comment: Checksum also has a relatively high chance of having a collision, where two non-identical sets of data have the same checksum. A HASHBYTES operation can be used for greater certainty, but the input needs to be converted into a single varchar/nvarchar/varbinary value.

Comment: @priyathapliyal You mentioned in the question that you didn't want to use a union. Can you please tell us why?